# In XSLT, is it possible to have a pointer to a function?

Tags: xml, xslt

Example:

```
<xsl:function name="my:function" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:param name="pNum" as="xs:integer" />
    <xsl:sequence select="$pNum * 2" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:sequence select="my:function(1)" />
```

I want to be able to call `my:function` , holding some reference to this function, if its possible.

The code below *does not* work, but intented to show what I am trying to do:

```
<xsl:variable name="vFn" select="my:function" />
<xsl:sequence select="$vFn(5)" />
```

I am running a transform against a plain text file, in mardown format, to convert it to html.  I'm not sure if it complicates things that I am not operating on an xml document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in XSLT 3.0 using `<xsl:variable name="vFn" select="my:function#1"/>`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-dynamic-function-invocation and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-named-function-ref.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps of interest to other people who come here: Dimitre Novatchev devised a way of doing this that works in XSLT 2.0 (or if you substitute named templates for functions, even in 1.0, with the node-set extension). (He also created a library called FXSL that exploits the technique).

Create a variable holding an element named after the function:

```
<xsl:variable name="my:function" as="element()">
  <my:function/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then create a template rule that matches this element and calls the function:

```
<xsl:template mode="dyn" match="my:function">
  <xsl:param name="p1"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="my:function($p1)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now define a function to do a dynamic call:

```
<xsl:function name="dyn:call">
  <xsl:param name="function"/>
  <xsl:param name="param"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$function" mode="dyn">
    <xsl:with-param name="p1" select="$param"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:function>
```

and now you can use the variable `$my:function` as a surrogate for the function, invoking it as

```
 ... select="dyn:call($my:function, 2)"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

**I. Here is an XSLT 1.0 example the technique that I used in FXSL**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:f1="8B9C63F4-F4AB5D11-994A0001-B4CD626F"
  xmlns:f2="AB02AC1C-1C65B3FF-77C5FFFE-4B329DA1" >
  <f1:f1/>
  <f2:f2/>

  <xsl:variable name = "vFun1" select = "document('')/*/f1:*[1]" />
  <xsl:variable name = "vFun2" select = "document('')/*/f2:*[1]" />

  <xsl:template match="f1:*">
      <xsl:param name = "pX" />
      <xsl:value-of select = "2 * $pX" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f2:*">
      <xsl:param name = "pX" />
      <xsl:value-of select = "3 * $pX" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match = "/">
    <xsl:call-template name = "mySum" >
      <xsl:with-param name = "pX" select = "3" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "pFun1" select = "$vFun1" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "pFun2" select = "$vFun2" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name = "mySum" >
    <xsl:param name = "pX" />
    <xsl:param name = "pFun1" select = "/.." />
    <xsl:param name = "pFun2" select = "/.." />

    <xsl:variable name = "vFx_1" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "$pFun1" >
        <xsl:with-param name = "pX" select = "$pX" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name = "vFx_2" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "$pFun2" >
        <xsl:with-param name = "pX" select = "$pX" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select = "$vFx_1 + $vFx_2" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template named `mySum` is passed two parameters that are "pointers to functions" of one argument, and a value for this single argument.

It invokes each of these dynamically passed functions, and produces the sum of the results.

As defined above, the two functions are: 1) `double(x)` and 2) `triple(x)`

Therefore, the result must be: `double(x) + triple(x)` that is: `5*x`

And indeed, the result is `15`, that is `5 * 3` . Here the transformation is applied on any XML document -- such as `<t/>` -- which is actually not used.

You are encouraged to modify the two functions and to see that each time the correct result is produced.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 implementation**:

As you can see, here the call actually passes what seems exactly as two functions:

```
f:applyAndSum(f:funTwice(), f:funFiveTimes(), 3)



<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:function name="f:apply">
   <xsl:param name="pFunc" as="element()"/>
   <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="$pFunc" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="$arg1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:apply">
   <xsl:param name="pFunc" as="element()"/>
   <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
   <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="$pFunc" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="$arg1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="arg2" select="$arg2"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
      "f:applyAndSum(f:funTwice(), f:funFiveTimes(), 3)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:applyAndSum">
    <xsl:param name="arg1" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg2" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg3"/>

    <xsl:sequence select=
      "f:apply($arg1,$arg3) + f:apply($arg2,$arg3)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:funTwice" as="element()">
     <f:funTwice/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:funFiveTimes" as="element()">
     <f:funFiveTimes/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="f:funTwice" mode="f:FXSL">
     <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

     <xsl:sequence select ="f:funTwice($arg1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f:funFiveTimes" mode="f:FXSL">
     <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

     <xsl:sequence select ="f:funFiveTimes($arg1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:funTwice">
     <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

     <xsl:sequence select="2*$arg1"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:funFiveTimes">
     <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

     <xsl:sequence select="5*$arg1"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here are two links for more systematic introduction into FXSL:

1. The [**original FXSL page**](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/) -- this is just XSLT 1.0,
2. A [**paper about FXSL 2**](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html) -- FXSL for XSLT 2.0